# Поведение CursorLoader при обновлении данных ContentProvider

Tags: android, cursor, content-type

Вопрос следующий:

Есть реализованный ContentProvider, где добавлены такие строки:

При получении курсора:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI);
```

При обновлении данных:

```
 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri, null);
```

В MainActivity идёт создание CursorLoader

```
return new CursorLoader(this, Provider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Сейчас получается при изменении данных по CONTENT_URI CursorLoader будет делать перезапуск?

Comment: похоже на правду. что мешает проверить?